# 'bootstrap4_form', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: bootstrap-4, django-forms

I am trying to use a Django bootstrap form. Here they show me this error:

**TemplateSyntaxError at /account/login/
Invalid block tag on line 14: 'bootstrap4_form', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?**

my html page is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}

  <div class="container">
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <form class="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}

      {% bootstrap4_form form %}
       <input type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-primary" value="Log in">
    </form>

  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here we should use just `{% bootstrap_form form %}` in place of `{% bootstrap4_form form %}`

hopefully, it will work.